# R: Expand a vector of matrix column numbers into a matrix with those columns filled

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

I have two vectors in R and want to generate a new matrix based on them.

```
a=c(1,2,1,2,3)      # a[1] is 1: thus row 1, column 1 should be equal to...
b=c(10,20,30,40,50) # ...b[1], or 10.
```

I want to produce matrix 'v' BUT without my 'for' loop through columns of v and my multiplication:

```
v = as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=length(a),ncol=length(unique(a))))
for(i in 1:ncol(v)) v[[i]][a==i] <- 1   # looping through columns of 'v'
v <- v*b
```

I am sure there is a fast/elegant way to do it in R. At least of expanding 'a' into the earlier version of 'v' (before its multiplication by 'b').

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the `a` index corresponds to the row and the `a` value corresponds to the column, and `b` is the value in the final matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly. a index is the row and a value is the column. And be is the value in the final matrix

Comment: should your matrix have max(a) columns instead of unique(a) columns?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way that sparse matrices can be defined.

```
Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = seq_along(a), j = a, x = b)
```

Comment: It's very interesting, thank you. However, it's about 60% slower than my original solution. In reality I have to deal with a very long 'a' and the final v has dozens of columns...

Comment: Actually, now that I increased the size of a and of its values, it looks like sparseMatrix might be faster!

Comment: Confirmed - the larger 'a' and the more values it has, the faster is sparseMatrix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, doing things like this with very large matrices is more or less what sparseMatrix is for.

Comment: The bigger your matrix (and the more of it that is 0s), the faster this will be.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Setup the problem:
set.seed(4242)
a <- sample(1:100, 1000000, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:500, length(a), replace = TRUE)  
# Start the timer 
start.time <- proc.time()[3]

# Actual code
# We use a matrix instead of a data.frame
# The  number of columns matches the largest column index in vector "a"
v <- matrix(0,nrow=length(a), ncol= max(a))
v[cbind(seq_along(a), a)] <- b

# Show elapsed time
stop.time <- proc.time()[3]
cat("elapsed time is: ", stop.time - start.time, "seconds.\n")

# For a million rows and a hundred columns, my prehistoric
# ... laptop says: elapsed time is:  2.597 seconds.

# these checks take much longer to run than the function itself
# Make sure the modified column in each row matches vector "a"
stopifnot(TRUE == all.equal(a, apply(v!=0, 1, which)))
# Make sure the modified value in each row equals vector "b"
stopifnot(TRUE == all.equal(rowSums(v), b))
```

Comment: Sorry, actually, does it do some resorting? a=rep(1:20,1000);
b=rep(1:20,1000); v<-as.data.frame(as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i = seq_along(a), j = a, x = b))) is not the same as v = as.data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=length(a),ncol=length(unique(a)))); v[col(v) == a] <- b

Comment: Ouch, you're right.  Sorry, insufficient testing on my part, the "<- b" assignment is by  column rather than row.  Try the revised revised edition.

Comment: thanks a lot for testing - it's a really cool solution. I really like it because it's logical, very fast and it's just using R base. I tested it (using your example) against sparseMatrix. For such a huge matrix it was just a tad slower: 2.57-2.6 seconds against 2.17-2.31 seconds. Not a big difference. Thanks a lot!